# No internet after sleep; "no ipv6 routers available"

Tags: arch-linux, dhcp, internet, netctl

I'm unable to connect to the internet after I resume from *suspend to ram*.
The problem appeared after I fixed resuming from *suspend to disk*  following [this answer](https://superuser.com/a/405922/481701).

I'm using netctl where the error is pretty much the same as if manually running dhcpcd:

```
$ sudo dhcpcd enp12s0
DUID ***numbers & letters & colons ***
enp12s0: IAID e3:ed:11:40
enp12s0: soliciting an IPv6 router
enp12s0: soliciting a DHCP lease
enp12s0: no IPv6 Routers available
timed out
dhcpcd exited
```

The arch wiki suggests extending the timeout; I tried with 40 seconds but no luck. And I don't think the problem lies there since I used to connect for no more than 5-10 seconds.

Forcing `--ipv4only` does not work, either.

<s>I tried stopping the `netctl` service before suspending, that didn't work, too.</s>
*Edit:* Now if I stop the netctl service before suspend I *do* have working internet after resume and `netctl start myservice`; I'll be using this routine from now on but I'm still curious how it worked before without having to do `netctl stop/start`.

Anything else I can do?

Comment: Are there any firmware or BIOS updates available? I've seen various derpiness from network cards involving IPv6 and sleep.

Comment: Haven't touched the BIOS for ages... I should probably see if I can update it. I'm not very well informed but is the BIOS involved when resuming from sleep? I thought it ran only on system boot right before e.g. GRUB.